# Python regex only matches in single-line mode not multi-line mode

Tags: python, regex, multiline

Why are there no regex matches when this is multiline, but it works on one line?

```py
Python 3.8.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Dec 26 2020, 05:05:16) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.20.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import re

In [2]: msg = r"""
   ...: (\(1054, "Unknown column 'inf(e0)?' in 'field list'"\))
   ...: |
   ...: (ProgrammingError: inf can not be used with MySQL)
   ...: """

In [3]: err_text = 'ProgrammingError: inf can not be used with MySQL'

In [4]: re.search(msg, err_text, re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
```

But if I don't break it up into multiple lines and omit the `re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE`, it works

```py
In [5]: msg2 = r"""(\(1054, "Unknown column 'inf(e0)?' in 'field list'"\))|(ProgrammingError: inf can not be used with MySQL)"""

In [6]: re.search(msg2, err_text)
Out[6]: <re.Match object; span=(0, 48), match='ProgrammingError: inf can not be used with MySQL'>
```

I've been trying to figure it out here https://regex101.com/r/tkju6f/1 but no luck.

(for [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/40556#issuecomment-830337852) PR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the newlines are considered literally and not ignored. Try instead using comments:

```
msg = r'''(?#
)(\(1054, "Unknown column 'inf(e0)?' in 'field list'"\))(?#
)|(?#
)(ProgrammingError: inf can not be used with MySQL)(?#
)'''
```

The parts between `(?#` and `)` will be ignored.

[Multiline mode](https://riptutorial.com/regex/example/15177/multiline-modifier) is not what you think: it just means that `^` (resp. `$`) is not meant to match the beginning (resp. ending) of the *string*, but the beginning (resp. ending) of the *line*.

Full execution:

```
>>> import re
>>> msg = r'''(?#
... )(\(1054, "Unknown column 'inf(e0)?' in 'field list'"\))(?#
... )|(?#
... )(ProgrammingError: inf can not be used with MySQL)(?#
... )'''
>>> err_text = 'ProgrammingError: inf can not be used with MySQL'
>>> print(re.search(msg, err_text))
<re.Match object; span=(0, 48), match='ProgrammingError: inf can not be used with MySQL'>
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/0RCkYp/1) you can find the fixed version of your regex101.

---

**EDIT**: If you don't want to modify the regular expression but just make it more readable, just break the python lines like this:

```
msg = r'''(\(1054, "Unknown column 'inf(e0)?' in 'field list'"\))''' + \
      r'''|''' + \
      r'''(ProgrammingError: inf can not be used with MySQL)'''
```

Comment: Thanks! but then seems silly to break it up into multiple lines, only to add verbose escaping of newlines... I'm only doing it to avoid flake8 errors of line too long